# How are Best Student Paper awards evaluated at engineering conferences?

Tags: publications, graduate-school, conference

Do Best Paper and Best Student Paper awards follow the same evaluation criteria at engineering conferences? If not, how do they differ besides the requirement for Best Student Paper to be authored by a student?

Comment: Almost certainly differs by conference. The conference or program committee may vote, or the reviewers may.

Comment: At the conferences I was involved in, there were not any separate criteria for best paper discussions. It was the same criteria as for the acceptance decision, but a best paper usually excelled in one or several of the criteria. For best student papers, it might be the same.